# Setting the xaml of the Silverlight 4 RichTextBox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

I can retrieve the xaml with rtb.xaml.ToString() and store it in a database. But how do I set it? As an example, I thought rtb2.Xaml = rtb.Xaml would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Xaml` property is a of type `String` so there is no need to use `ToString` on it.

You simply store the content of `Xaml` as a string in a database and restore it later with a simply assignment:-

```
 rtb.Xaml = myXamlString;
```

Howeever you should note that only a limited number of elements will actuall serialise in this wa, you can't expect embedded controls like `ComboBox` to serialise.  In addition only relevant properties of the remaining elements will serialise, again those related to the appearance of the text.

For details see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.xaml(v=VS.95).aspx).